# Two "One to One" relationships between two classes

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have entity `Customer` and entity `Ticket`.

`Customer` can have two different tickets. `List` of Tickets and `OneToMany` relationship is not suitable there, because I should have two different fields in `Customer` entity for tickets: `ownTicket` and `refererTicket`. Please help me implement this relationship. How it can be done?

Comment: What exactly is your Problem? Just using two different fields with their own JoinColumn/FK should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map it as a `@OneToMany` but hide this implementation detail. This could look as below: ticket has an extra column indicating its type.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "ticket_type")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.String)
    private Map<TicketType, Ticket> tickets;

    // we will not expose the tickets collection
    // the fact it is a @OneToMany is then transparent to all client code

    public Ticket getOwnTicket(){
        return tickets.get(TicketType.O);
    }

    public Ticket getReferrerTicket(){
        return tickets.get(TicketType.R); 
    }

    public void setOwnTicket(Ticket ticket){
        //ticket.setType(TicketType.O); //may not be required
        tickets.put(TicketType.O, ticket);
    }

    public void setReferrerTicket(Ticket ticket){
        //ticket.setType(TicketType.R); //may not be required
        tickets.put(TicketType.R, ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very cool solution! Thank you very much! I really appreciate this:)

Answer (score 2):

You can have two one to one relationships, like so:

```
class Costumer {
    @OneToOne
    Ticket ownTicket;

    @OneToOne
    Ticket refererTicket;
}
```

Just give different names. And then, in the Ticket class, if you do want to map both ways, I believe you have to use the mappedBy property:

```
class Ticket {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="ownTicket")
    Costumer owner;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="refererTicket")
    Costumer referer;
}
```

If Ticket can have only one Costumer, then this is what I would do:

Create a relationship class, called `TicketCostumer` or something:

```
class TicketCostumer {
    @OneToOne
    Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne
    Costumer costumer;

    Type type;
}
```

Where Type is an enum you create that has OWNER and REFERER;

Now each ticket can have only one of this:

```
class Ticket {
    @OneToOne
    CostumerTicket ct;
}
```

And finally, on Costumer, you can decide how to handle things; you could have a list and guarantee by hand that there is not more than one of each kind (or try to use the @UniqueBy or something like that), or you can have two separated fields to control it.

Comment: But Ticket should have only one Customer field, one ticket can be mapped only to one customer, but customer can have two different tickets

Comment: @Yuriy I uppdated my answer considering this case. I thought one ticket could have both an owner and a referer. But it seems that it can have either but not both, so I updated.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem?

You can easily create Customer as:

```
public class Customer{
  ....
  @OneToOne
  Ticket ownTicket;

  @OneToOne
  Ticket refererTicket;
  ....
}
```

Comment: And Ticket class will have only one field Customer? not two?